# Recycler View showing only very last item added to realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a firebase strucuture as

[image: database]

The recycler view is only displaying the last added or say latest added node to the database instead of displaying each and every node

the database reference i am using is

```java
r2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads").child("Wheat").child(S).child(D).child(T).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
```

and the code for recycler view is as

```java
public class MyPost extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference r, r2, r3;
    private String S, D, T;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder2> Fbra1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_post);
        r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User_Data").child(MainDashboard.type).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.R_view2);
        r.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(rr);
    }


    private ValueEventListener rr = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            S = dataSnapshot.child("State").getValue().toString();
            D = dataSnapshot.child("City").getValue().toString();
            T = dataSnapshot.child("Tehsil").getValue().toString();
            //   Toast.makeText(MyPost.this,S+D+T.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            r2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Uploads").child("Wheat").child(S).child(D).child(T).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
            //   Toast.makeText(MyPost.this,r2.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            r2.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    r3=r2.child(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    Toast.makeText(MyPost.this, r3.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RecyclerCropView> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecyclerCropView>().setQuery(r3, RecyclerCropView.class).build();
                    Fbra1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder2>(options) {
                        @Override
                        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder2 holder, int position, @NonNull RecyclerCropView model) {
                            holder.setProductImage(model.getProduct_Image());
                            holder.setProduct(model.getProduct());
                            holder.setMax(model.getMaximumPrice());
                            holder.setQuantityUnit(model.getQuantityUnit());
                            holder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
                        }

                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public ViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_post, parent, false);
                            return new ViewHolder2(v);
                        }
                    };
                    Fbra1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyPost.this));
                    Fbra1.startListening();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(Fbra1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        finish();
    }


}
```

**Recycler view is only showing very last item that was added to database.**

**Note:-**

- The item.xml file has width set to wrap content.
- if i remove the childEventListener the recyclerView shows multiple items with 
  null on the place of TextView(These are those textView on which data retrived was supposed to be set)

Comment: the structure you have is very bad. Please explain why you have multiple listeners

Comment: Actually i have to also search on the basis of state -> district-> tehsil (city)  so the data is arranged as such that it could be referenced as per user reference

Comment: And user could perform search operation easyly

Comment: then you should construct a reference to that node, and just use firebase recycler UI to get the data. so far you are not using the 3 listeners you have added. Replace with the code in my answer, where r2=the node with the list of items.

Comment: Can u provide a sample code for reference please 
I do not get your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem: `r2.addChildEventListener`

> Classes implementing this interface can be used to receive events about changes in the child locations of a given DatabaseReference ref. Attach the listener to a location using addChildEventListener(ChildEventListener) and the appropriate method will be triggered when changes occur. 
>   [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener)

What you should use is a `r2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

This returns the children of the specific node. But now since you are using `FirebaseUI` library, you will not need to listen as it is a listener itself.

So your code should listen to the root of the posts. This `r3=r2.child(dataSnapshot.getKey());` is unnecessary because it only gets one entry

Change to this

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RecyclerCropView> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RecyclerCropView>().setQuery(r2, RecyclerCropView.class).build();
Fbra1 = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RecyclerCropView, ViewHolder2>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder2 holder, int position, @NonNull RecyclerCropView model) {
        holder.setProductImage(model.getProduct_Image());
        holder.setProduct(model.getProduct());
        holder.setMax(model.getMaximumPrice());
        holder.setQuantityUnit(model.getQuantityUnit());
        holder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder2 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_post, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder2(v);
    }
};
Fbra1.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.hasFixedSize();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MyPost.this));
Fbra1.startListening();
recyclerView.setAdapter(Fbra1);
```

Comment: This did work in my case it shows empty items with null in place of textviews

Comment: Hey @MoHiTGuPtA it means it worked, what is missing is is the text view are getting null values because probably the values dont contain the values in model. You can show the model to know if you are pointing to the right list. Simply call `Log.d();`. if they are not correct, check reference `r3`

Comment: Yeh actually i eventually changed my database a bit 
Removed post from there and listed all the items under 18Oct.. Instead of post and then used solution by you and it finally worked 

Understood one thing eventually that while using firebase Ui there shouldn't be multiple childs after reference this makes an error @Lucem

Comment: am glad i helped. Happy coding @MoHiTGuPtA