# FirebaseUI RecycleView only displays first item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I updated to firebase-ui 6.3.0 which doesn't have the populateViewHolder method anymore. I changed the code according to the examples I found online. RecycleView didn't show anything until I added adapter.startListening() to the onStart method of my home activity.

The problem is that only 1 item is displayed and can't figure it out why. Since I use         linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true) the item displayed is the last item, but if I comment out that line the first item is displayed (and the context manu doesn't work either).

I checked some similiar StackOverflow questions but couldn't find the problem.

[Firebase RecyclerView OnDataChanged only last element is Shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51042250/firebase-recyclerview-ondatachanged-only-last-element-is-shown/51043495)

[Recycler View showing only very last item added to realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886215/recycler-view-showing-only-very-last-item-added-to-realtime-database)

Here are my classes and xmls:

HomeActivity:

```
    private RecyclerView transactionsRecyclerView;
    private TransactionRecordAdapter transactionRecordAdapter;

    private FirebaseHelper firebaseHelper;
    private Query query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
 
        firebaseHelper = new FirebaseHelper();

        query = this.firebaseHelper.getTransactionRecordsOrderedByDateQuery();
        // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(ConstantStringValue.DB_CHILD_TRANSACTION_RECORDS).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
        // .orderByChild("date");
        
        transactionsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.transactionsRecyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        transactionsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, VERTICAL);
        transactionsRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        registerForContextMenu(transactionsRecyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        transactionRecordAdapter = new TransactionRecordAdapter(TransactionRecord.class, query, this);
        transactionsRecyclerView.setAdapter(transactionRecordAdapter);
        transactionRecordAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        transactionRecordAdapter.stopListening();
    }
```

TransactionRecordAdapter:

```
    private int position;
    private String selectedItemId;
    private Context context;

    public TransactionRecordAdapter(Class<TransactionRecord> modelClass, Query ref, Context context) {
        super(new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TransactionRecord>()
                .setQuery(ref, modelClass)
                .build());
        this.context = context;
     }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getSelectedItemId() {
        return selectedItemId;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemId(String selectedItemId) {
        this.selectedItemId = selectedItemId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TransactionRecordViewHolder holder, int position,
                                    @NonNull TransactionRecord model) {

         holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            setPosition(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            setSelectedItemId(holder.getId());
            return false;
        });

        holder.setAnnouncement(model.getAnnouncement());
        ...
        holder.setId(this.getRef(position).getKey());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TransactionRecordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.transrecord, parent, false);
        return  new TransactionRecordViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(TransactionRecordViewHolder holder) {
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    }
```

TransactionRecordViewHolder:

```
    private View view;
    private String id;

    public TransactionRecordViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

    // ... setters

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo) {
        contextMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.editTransHomeContext,
                Menu.NONE, "Szerkesztés");
        contextMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.deleteTransHomeContext,
                Menu.NONE, "Törlés");
    }
```

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="hu.beczdev.cashbudget.activity.HomeActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/transactionsRecyclerView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

transrecord.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transAmountTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:paddingStart="25dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="25dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingStart="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/transCatNameTextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:paddingStart="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/transCommentView"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue not in firebase as it already returned a row, you at least need to `wrap_content` of the height of your list item to not occupy the entire height of the `RecyclerView`.

so in transrecord.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Comment: It was a good suggestion. I changed the height and now every element is visible. Thanks!